# Promise not called after await

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

#### Problem

Why in the following code, the second `foo()` doesn't get called?

```js
function foo() {
  console.log("--- entering foo ---")
  return new Promise(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("--- resolved ---")
    }, 2000)
  })
}

async function bar() {
  await foo()
  foo() // not called
}

bar()
```

To clarify some trials I've done:

#### Working

```js
foo()
foo()
```

```js
foo()
await foo()
```

#### Not working

```js
await foo()
foo() // not called
```

```js
await foo()
await foo() // not called
```

Comment: 30s to get -1, that was quick. Any explanation as to why?

Comment: The promise is never resolved, so `await` gets stuck. Printing "resolved" to console does not actually resolve the promise.

Comment: a `console.log('---resolved---')` does not resolve a promise and the `await` waits forever a resolution or rejection that will never happen

Comment: guys I do not agree about downvoting his question. I mean, yes the promise is not resolved, that's the issue. But actually he posted code, trials, clearly stated his issue. What are you downvoting? the difficulty of the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your promise in `foo` is not resolved, so the `await foo()` stucks. Resolve your promise inside `foo`:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log("--- entering foo ---")
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("--- resolved ---")
      resolve()
    }, 2000)
  })
}

async function bar() {
  await foo()
  foo()
}

bar();
```

Comment: You could improve the quality of your answer by explaining what you did, why you did that, and illustrating it with a working snippet (not just a block of code). Then I will upvote :)

Comment: added a snippet and a comment to add some more explanation and the working example

Comment: @quirimmo I could have done that myself, but I preferred educating OP ;)

Comment: @JeremyThille sorry I was already editing when you were writing your comment, I read it when edit was already submit :)